# Grails 2.0.0.RC3: Could not reload changes to controller, java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1323622798918

Tags: grails, grails-controller

This error has been popping up lately since I started evaluating Grails 2.0.0.RC3. 
I make simple changes to a controller, then save.

From `pictureList.count()` which somehow worked in 1.3.7 but not in 2.0.0RC3

```
def tagged = {
        def pictureList = Picture.findAllByTag(params.id)
        render(view: 'list', model: [pictureInstanceList:pictureList, 
            tag:params.id, pictureInstanceTotal:pictureList.count()])
}
```

To `pictureList.size()` which makes more sense as pictureList is of type ArrayList

```
def tagged = {
        def pictureList = Picture.findAllByTag(params.id)
        render(view: 'list', model: [pictureInstanceList:pictureList, 
            tag:params.id, pictureInstanceTotal:pictureList.size()])
}
```

I get the compiling output message letting me know whats going on.

```
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
```

Then I reload the page and I get this.

```
| Error 2011-12-11 17:00:01,908 [Thread-7] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  
- Plugin [controllers:2.0.0.RC3] could not reload changes to file 
[/Users/gotomanners/Documents/Projects/sampleProject/grails-app/controllers/sampleProject/PictureController.groovy]: 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1323622798918
Message: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1323622798918
   Line | Method
->> 632 | doCall in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure5
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   680 | run    in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoSuchFieldException: __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1323622798918
->> 1882 | getDeclaredField in java.lang.Class
```

Now the only way to recover from the error(that I've found out) is to restart the application.

Has anyone come across this issue?? I'll try to isolate the issue, if possible, so i can submit a bug report.

I should add that this app was originally based on grails 1.3.7 and I've recently upgraded it to 2.0.0RC1 and now to 2.0.0RC3

Comment: Have you tried asking on the mailing list?

Comment: I've come across this too with 2.0.0.RC3. If you can reproduce it consistently, I'd suggest submitting a bug report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use Intellij Idea and run grails app with it?
If so, you might try this temporary solution as offered on Idea's [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-78396):

> add enable.groovy.hotswap=false to /bin/idea.properties and restart IDEA.

This fixed this issue for me

Comment: Does this prevent reloading of the classes though?  If so it isn't a great help -

Comment: This issue was a bug in intelliJ 10. Fixed it by going command line with grails, using a workaround outlined above or upgrading to Intellij 11

Comment: Confirmed that adding enable.groovy.hotswap=false to /bin/idea.properties prevents the issue, and still allows changes to be reloaded by Grails on the fly.  Nice workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Press **cntl + alt + G** and run **clean** command in Intellij Idea.. it must work

Worked for me

if that doesn't work, add add enable.groovy.hotswap=false to /bin/idea.properties  then run **clean**

Works too!!